# Error saving DateField (with null value) using Vaadin SQL Container

Tags: java, date, vaadin

I have some fields binded to a table using a Vaadin `SQLContainer`. One of them is a `PopupDateField` field binded in this way:

```
FieldGroupVar.bind(field, "dateOfBorn");
```

But some of the date values can have NULLs, so when the app try to retrieve or store the values in the table a null pointer exception is throws.

For example when doing> `FieldGroupVar.commit();`

How can tell `SQLContainer` that ommit this error and store or retrieve the rest of the values?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need need to set the nullRepresentation
field.setNullRepresetnation(new Date());

I hope this could help.

Comment: Unfortunately the PopupDateField doesnt have a setNullRepresetnation method. I was thinking maybe using the addCommitHandler but this posible just work for a commit but not in the case when the field is automatically loadly from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I use the ternary operator within the insert statement.
It checks Date field if it is null, and if yes, it inserts current date:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (MYDATE) VALUES('+
(rs.getTimestamp("MYDATE") != null ? rs.getTimestamp("MYDATE") : new Date())
+"')";
```